# How to change DOM elements, using javascript, depending on the screen size of a client

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on this event slider which has 3 posts with left, right scroll buttons.
but i am new to responsive designs, and i want to change the whole content including all the elements in the DIV once the screen size reduces to 1000px.
please help me with some ideas to go through.

Comment: Why JS? this sounds like a job for CSS media queries.

Comment: JS is not required. You can even do this simple CSS media queries...

Comment: with media query i can change the content, which is already listed in the DOM elements, what i want is to change the elements itself, like i do not want the whole slider there, and once the screen size will be small, i want to introduce a whole new slider with different content and different attributes, is it possible with media-queries

Answer (score 1):

Have a look below example using css media queries, it may help you.

```css
<style>
 @media(min-width:1000px) {
     .hide-on-desktop {
         display:none;
     };
 }

 @media(max-width:999px) and (min-width:767px) {
     .hide-on-laptop {
         display:none;
     };
 }

 @media(max-width:766px) {
     .hide-on-mobile {
         display:none;
     };
 }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="hide-on-desktop hide-on-laptop"> for mobile </div>
<div class="hide-on-desktop hide-on-mobile"> for laptop </div>
<div class="hide-on-laptop hide-on-mobile"> for desktop </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css use a media query with a max-width of 1000px. Inside the media query apply some css that will only come into effect on devices that are <= 1000px.

```
@media(max-width:1000px){
 /* So  in here you might want to apply some css to stack your posts one after the other and to hide your left and right scroll buttons*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define something like this in CSS

```
div {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

or you can use media for set font size in the CSS file

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
    body {
        font-size: 10px;
    };
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    body {
        font-size: 11px;
    };
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    body {
        font-size: 12px;
    };
}

@media(min-width:1200px) {
    body {
        font-size: 13px;
    };
}
```

Then set font-sizes on each and every elements you want to resize font while resizing browser or according to resolution in percentage.

eg: if you want to resize fonts on h1

```
h1 {
   font-size: 150%;
}
```

it will work as you want it to.

**EDIT:**
I think you need to resize te screen according to Desktop and Tablet and mobile if that it is then maybe this help--

Assuming this HTML:

```
<div id="some_container">
    <nav id="n1">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <nav id="n2">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

You will only need the following CSS:

```
#n1{
    display:none;
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width : 1000px) {
    #n1{
        display:block;
    }
    #n2{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

The great thing about this way is that it's very scaleable. Need this "effect" on a different page? You'll only have to edit [u]that[/u] page. No messing around with JavaScript, hard-coding new classes / cases.

Comment: thanks @shubham, 
well, i wanted to know, that with the help of media query, is it possible to change the DOM element itself, in my current requirement, i want to change the slider in to whole new slider with different id and class and with different attribute, it like once the screen will drop to 1000px,  i want a new elements to be introduced in DOM -

Comment: @thanks for the tip, i think i have understood now, before i was trying to catch the same element with js and was editing the elements internally, once the screen size drops.
i guess i need to thorough the media-query concept again.
thanks again

Comment: @KrDigvijaySinghChampawat that sounds good...please vote up if I helped

Comment: i was voting you up, but i think, i lack on reputation as of now, once par with it, will surely up vote you.

Comment: @KrDigvijaySinghChampawat than accept it :P it will give you some point ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS media queries instead of using Javascript. Less code and more efficient

```
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
  #yourDiv {
     /*Add css property to your div when its 1001px or more*/
  }
}

 @media (max-width: 1000px) {
   #yourDiv {      
      /*Add css property to your div when its 1000px or less*/
   }
 }
```

Check this link for more examples: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp